# Unable to play video from raw folder using signed .apk generated by Maven

Tags: android, maven, android-activity

I am using Maven scripting (pom.xml) file to generate signed and unsigned .apk.
I am able to generate signed and unsigned .apk successfully using Maven.
But, unfortunately, in unsigned .apk application is able to play videos from "raw" folder and in signed .apk it shows in logs below and doesn't play video

```
Failed to open file 'android.resource://com.brodos.kiosk.de.brodosnet_21_5/2131099648'. (No such file or directory)
```

So, it would be good that someone could answer the reason for this problem.

Comment: Have you actually looked into the signed APK to see if your resources are there? You can use unzip or apktool or other tools for this.

Comment: @DavidWasser yes. I have already unzip signed APK and I can easily find videos under "raw" folder

Comment: @DurgeshPatel are you using correct keystore file and password?

Comment: @LalitPoptani yes. I am using correct keystore to sign APK